# dynamic array of strings, but i get heap corruption detected

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-to-pointer, arrayofarrays, arrayofstring

I try to make a dynamic array of char pointer, what means does pointers can be a dynamic memory too, so in the code above I try to allocate one size to the array and in him, allocate to the first object a string. But I get an error "heap corruption detected" on the array pointer.

```
int main(void)
{

    char** pArr = 0;
    char string[] = "hello";

    pArr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); //make it an array with one element
    *pArr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(string) + 1)); //make it an array with the size of string
    strcpy(*pArr, string); //copy string to the first element of the array

    printf("%p", pArr); //the pointer where the heap corruption is detected

    free(pArr);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I copied the whole main so you know I did nothing expect that.

Comment: Use  pArr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char *));

Comment: `* 1` is pointless and just clutters the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate enough space here:

```
pArr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
```

You only allocate space for 1 `char` instead of 1 `char *`.  So you end up writing past the end of allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To allocate the correct amount of space:

```
pArr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1);
```

Or better yet:

```
pArr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 1);
```

Comment: yeah you right, so the pointers have their own size thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @ArturKarabekov Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.